# dc linecharts in a composite chart with group reduction using reduce callback methods

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, linechart, composition

I want to make a composite chart with an unknown number of lincharts all based on the same dimension but each of them with call-back reduction functions to calculate count, sum and average but every one filtering data for a given field value of the dimension.

I don't know how to make it work. The graph coordinates and legends appear but no line is painted.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
var tablaCount = dc.dataCount("#dataCount");
var tablaDatos = dc.dataTable("#tabla");

var ofs = 0, pag = 10, ndxSize = 0;
var ndx, all;
d3.json("/PruebaConcepto/json/userdashboard-vgodoy-pruebax_20181023111343.json").then(function(data) {
    ndx = crossfilter(data);
    ndxSize = ndx.size();
    all = ndx.groupAll();

    var compositeChartline1 = dc.compositeChart("#lineChartline1");
    var dimensionline1 = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return [d.horasacta, d.aerodromo] ; });
    var groupline1 = dimensionline1.group().reduce(
    function (p, v) {
        ++p.count;
        p.pct = (p.count / ndxSize) * 100;
        p.sum += ("viento_int_viento" != "kpigroup" ? (v.viento_int_viento ? v.viento_int_viento : 0) : 0);
        p.avg = ((p.sum ? p.sum : 0) / p.count);
        return p;
    },
    function (p, v) {
        --p.count;
        p.pct = (p.count / ndxSize) * 100;
        p.sum -= ("viento_int_viento" != "kpigroup" ? (v.viento_int_viento ? v.viento_int_viento : 0) : 0);
        p.avg = ((p.sum ? p.sum : 0) / p.count);
        return p;
    },
    function () {
        return {count: 0, pct: 0, sum: 0, avg: 0};
    }
    );

    var keysline1 = groupline1.all().filter(function(d) {return d.key[0]});
    var seriesline1 = [];
    var tmpseriesline1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < keysline1.length; i++) {
        tmpseriesline1.push(keysline1[i].key[1]);
    }
    seriesline1 = (tmpseriesline1.filter(function(item, pos) { return tmpseriesline1.indexOf(item) == pos;})).slice();
    tmpseriesline1 = 0;

    var yMaxline1 = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < groupline1.size() && !(groupline1.top(Infinity)[i] == null); i++) {
        if (yMaxline1 < groupline1.top(Infinity)[i].value.avg) {
        yMaxline1 = groupline1.top(Infinity)[i].value.avg;
        }
    }
    var yMagline1 = Math.pow(10, Math.floor((Math.log(yMaxline1) / Math.LN10 + 0.000000001))) / 10;
    yMaxline1 = Math.ceil(yMaxline1 + yMagline1);

    var xRangeline1 = [];
    var tmpxRangeline1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < keysline1.length; i++) {
        tmpxRangeline1.push(keysline1[i].key[0]);
    }
    xRangeline1 = tmpxRangeline1.filter(function(item, pos) { return tmpxRangeline1.indexOf(item) == pos;});
    tmpxRangeline1 = 0;

    var color = ["red", "green", "yellow"];
    var groupsline1 = [seriesline1.length];
    var lineChartsline1 = [seriesline1.length];
    for (var i = 0; i < seriesline1.length; i++) {
    var tmpSeriesline1 = seriesline1[i]
    var tmpGroupline1 = dimensionline1.group().reduce(
                                    function (p, v) {
                                        ++p.count;
                                        p.pct = (p.count / ndxSize) * 100;
                                        p.sum += ("viento_int_viento" != "kpigroup" ? (v.viento_int_viento ? v.viento_int_viento : 0) : 0);
                                        p.avg = ((p.sum ? p.sum : 0) / p.count);
                                        return p;
                                    },
                                    function (p, v) {
                                        --p.count;
                                        p.pct = (p.count / ndxSize) * 100;
                                        p.sum -= ("viento_int_viento" != "kpigroup" ? (v.viento_int_viento ? v.viento_int_viento : 0) : 0);
                                        p.avg = ((p.sum ? p.sum : 0) / p.count);
                                        return p;
                                    },
                                    function () {
                                        return {count: 0, pct: 0, sum: 0, avg: 0};
                                    }
                                );

    groupsline1[i] = tmpGroupline1.all().filter(function(d) { return d.key[1] == tmpSeriesline1; });

    lineChartsline1[i] = dc.lineChart(compositeChartline1)
                                .group(groupsline1[i], seriesline1[i])
                                .valueAccessor(function(d) { 
                                    return parseFloat(d.value.avg); 
                                })
                                .title(function(d) {
                                    var s = [];
                                    s.push(d.key[1] + ":");
                                    s.push("Conteo: " + (isNaN(d.value.count) ? "-" : d.value.count + " (" + d.value.pct.toFixed(2) + "%)"));
                                    if ("avg" != "count") {
                                        s.push("Media: " + (isNaN(d.value.avg) ? "-" : d.value.avg.toFixed(2) + ("avg" != "pct" ? "" : "%")));
                                    }
                                    return s.join("\n");
                                })
                                .colors(color[i])
                                .dashStyle([5,5]);
    }

    compositeChartline1
    .width(500).height(500)
    .margins({top: 60, right: 60, bottom: 120, left: 120})
    .x(d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(xRangeline1))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .y(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, yMaxline1]).range([500,0]))
    .xAxisLabel("X")
    .yAxisLabel("Y")
    .legend(dc.legend().x(40).y(20).itemHeight(seriesline1.length).gap(10))
    .dimension(dimensionline1)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .brushOn(false)
    .elasticY(true)
    .renderlet(function (chart) { 
    chart.selectAll('g.x text').attr('transform', 'translate(-30,30) rotate(315)'); 
    })
    .compose(lineChartsline1);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `dc` tag can't be right. Which programming language is this? `linechart` might be a relevant tag, but it will not help anyone find this question. Make sure you tag your question with the proper programming language tag. People who answer questions use language tags to filter questions, so if the language tag is wrong or missing, it's very unlikely that you will get an answer.

Comment: Thanks @HåkenLid, your change brought this question to my attention. :)

Comment: Hi @Marvin - this isn't a complete question. It's certainly possible to make computed reductions and there are hundreds of examples on SO and other places. Try the crossfilter keyword perhaps? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi. What I want to do is to compose a chart with two or more line charts but I need to group the data making some extra calculations. So I need a more complex reduction but I don't know how to make it in the case of a grouping for a composite chart.

Comment: I've added to the message part of my code.

Comment: Ordinarily each child chart takes its own group (but they share the same dimension). So there's no need to make the reduction more complex for the sake of a composite chart. Complex reductions are usually for averages, stddev, min max... or you might want to reduce a while bunch of values at once. The [annotated stock example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) has a few of these.

Comment: HI, I've added the reduction function to my code for a more complete explanation. Thanks.

Comment: You still haven't said what the problem is, besides the absurd claim that "no one tells how to implement"... what are you trying to do and what is failing, please?? I can see that `ndxSize` is possibly a problem, as it won't get updated when the record count changes. But I don't like to guess. Please, just ask a question?!

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using the same group for all the charts - unclear what `groupline1` is, do you intend it to reduce the data for all the lines, and then split them out again? Personally I would just use a group per child chart but again it's unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I already said what a want to do. The problem? I don't know, it just doesn't work. I've changed the whole message and added the complete code. Thank you for your help and apologise for the inconveniences.